# R: Simulating Points from a Normal Distribution

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Consider the following situation - for a Normal Distribution with mean=5 and sigma=5:

- A) Based on numerical integration, what is the probability of observing a point greater than 7?
- B) Based on simulations (e.g. 1000 simulations), what is the probability of observing a point greater than 7?

Ideally, the answer for A) and B) should be the same:

```
library(MASS)
mu <- 5
sigma <- 5

# nmerically integrate to find P(X > 7)
 1 - pnorm(7, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
#[1] 0.3445783

# Simulation
set.seed(123)  
simulated_points <- rnorm(1000, mean = mu, sd = sigma)

# Find the percentage of points greater than 5
sum(simulated_points > 7) / length(simulated_points) * 100
#[1] 33.7
```

As we can see, the above results match.

**My Question:** Suppose now I have a 2 dimensional multivariate normal distribution with  `mu1 = 1, mu2 = 2, sigma1 = 3, sigma2 = 6, sigma12 = sigma=21=5`

- A) Based on numerical integration, what is the probability of observing a point greater than (2,3)?
- B) Based on simulations (e.g. 1000 simulations), what is the probability of observing a point greater than (2,3)?

I tried to do this myself:

```
library(mvtnorm)

mu <- c(1, 2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(9, 5, 5, 36), nrow=2)  # Covariance matrix

   # Numerically integrate

p_x1_gt_2_and_x2_gt_3 <- pmvnorm(lower = -Inf, upper = c(2, 3), mean = mu, sigma = Sigma)

# Simulate 1000 points 
set.seed(123)  
simulated_points <- mvrnorm(100000, mu = mu, Sigma = Sigma)

percentage_gt_2_and_3 <- sum(simulated_points[,1] > 2 & simulated_points[,2] > 3) / nrow(simulated_points) * 100
```

However, the results do not match:

```
> p_x1_gt_2_and_x2_gt_3
[1] 0.3990654

> percentage_gt_2_and_3
[1] 20.307
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: somewhat unrelated but I am not sure that using pnorm is calculated using numerical integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pmvnorm call is wrong, here you are looking at the density from -Inf to (2,3), while what you are interested in is the density from (2,3) to +Inf.

```
> p_x1_gt_2_and_x2_gt_3 <- pmvnorm(lower = c(2, 3), upper=c(Inf,Inf), mean = mu, sigma = Sigma)
[1] 0.2023229
attr(,"error")
[1] 1e-15
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```